# color codes in reportlabs-python

Tags: python, colors, reportlab

I'm using reportlabs library of python to generate PDF reports. I need to understand which format of color code is needed to be passed.

When I pass RGB code for light green (178,255,102), to `the_canvas.setFillColorRGB(178,255,102)` it gives me white. And if I provide universal RGB color code for any color, it still gives me the same white color.

If I provide (25,51,0) , it gives me yellow, which is not RGB code for yellow.

How should I provide color codes to the reportlab in order to get the color I wanted. Which format is it using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I can tell, using the 256 color space won't work. The manual states that using 1 is 'all lights on full'. So, to create `256,256,256` is actually done by using `(1,1,1)`. Thus, to get something in between, you'll have to use decimals. For me, I wanted the `RGB: (75,116,156)` so I had to write: `setFillColorRGB(0.29296875,0.453125,0.609375)`. That's the equivelant to: `75/256, 116/256, 156/256.` A bit ridiculous IMO, but it came out perfect

Comment: Your answer was like a light in the dark. However for me dividing by 255 did the trick not 256. But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone wants an example I did this.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
...
...
other code
...
...
customColor = colors.Color(red=(255.0/255),green=(204.0/255),blue=(153.0/255))
```

I used this color for a Table Style